# IIS 7 - providing access to developers without giving admin rights

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

I know that IIS7 allows you to provide access to perform dev work on a box without being an admin.  I see a lot of high level overviews of this capability.  Does anyone have experience with doing this sort of thing?

What I have is a server (Windows 2008 R2) that I'd like to provide minimum access to for developers.  What have you guys done?  I know you can provide access to the server, site, or even app pool.  I just don't have experience and I thought I'd query people in this regard.

Edit:  I should note this is an Active Directory environment so I'd be giving access to domain users.

Answer (score 0):

Well if it's just to do testing under IIS 7 you now have the option for using [IIS Express](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx) and run on XP or better. Just a thought if your doing it for dev reasons.

Comment: Yes, I did see that option.  I already have 3 VMs setup.  A test, dev, production vm.  I'm going to play around with the permissions.  There are a lot of neat features like delegating functions in IIS to users as well.

Comment: Oh, another neat thing is SQL CE being optimized for web connections.  That wasn't the case before.  However, that's a bit off topic.

Comment: Off topic but a good topic, I've been looking for a good reason to play with SQL CE.